# Excel: Click button to copy row onto another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I know, I know. There are a ton of suggestions how to solve that particular problem, but somehow they all tend to fail with me.

What I have (simplified): A  (Mac) Excel-Sheet "Output" with:

```
Name   Time   Date
Mike   08:00  01.01.2016
```

The second row is yielding the data based on some input on yet another sheet.

What I need:
Whenever I will change the second row of "Output" (i.e. changing the input), I can click a button to add the entire second row onto a new worksheet "Log" (that will feature a header as well). Essentially logging the data upon clicking the button. The data can only be added once, multiple entries of the same data are deleted. After logging the data in "Log", the second row of "Output" does not need to be cleared, however I should not be able to add the same data again.

Any thoughts?

*EDIT

I modified the code from here: http://goo.gl/48jjDo.

```
Sub Submit()  
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim refTable As Variant, trans As Variant  
refTable = Array("A = A2", "B = B2", "C=C2")  
Dim Row As Long  
Row = Worksheets("Log").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1   
 For Each trans In refTable  
 Dim Dest As String, Field As String  
Dest = Trim(Left(trans, InStr(1, trans, "=") - 1)) & Row  
Field = Trim(Right(trans, Len(trans) - InStr(1, trans, "=")))  
Worksheets("Log").Range(Dest).value = Worksheets("Output").Range(Field).value  
Next  

Application.ScreenUpdating = True  

End Sub
```

*Edit2

Ok this got me further:

```
Sub CopyRangeFromSheet1toSheet2()
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' then next free   row in sheet2
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:C2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" &   lastRow)
End Sub
```

However, how do I check now for multiple data? And I will need to paste only the values.

Comment: Please post what code you do have.  Also, you say you've looked around but can't get a solution to work - what have you found? You're mainly looking to copy a row to a second sheet, overwriting any info on that second sheet?

Comment: I basically look for a way to copy a row onto a second sheet but not overwriting it but rather add it below it onto the first free row in the second sheet.

Comment: Just use `Activesheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` to find the last row in your second sheet and put your data into the next row.

Answer (score 0):

So far this works:

```
Sub CopyFormulas()  
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Sheets("Output")
Set sht2 = Sheets("Log")

sht1.Range("A2:C2").Copy
sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Application.CutCopyMode = False

response = MsgBox("data was added")

End Sub
```

Not it is only the check for multiple entries that is missing